# Laravel pagination problem with User::find($user_id)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I got this piece of code in Laravel:

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id; // gets the current user id
    $user = User::find($user_id); // find the specific user id

    $validPosts = $user->posts->paginate(5)->whereIn('status', ['Pending', 'Processing']);
    return view('home', compact('validPosts'));
}
```

I want to return all posts that have the `status` pending and processing with pagination that has the value of `5` but I am getting the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
>   exist.

I know that I have failed somewhere at `$user->posts->paginate(5)`.

What should I do?

Comment: Call the the posts() method in this way:  $user->posts()->paginate(5),

when you call $user->posts you receive a collection and you dont have method paginate() there

Comment: I did that and now I am getting another error when doing this to the view: "{{ $validPosts->links() }}"

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: @AndreiIonut That is because $validPosts is an array.  You probably want to loop through the array to get the links.

Comment: Remove compact method, that is odd. Use all advantages of Eloquent.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results

Comment: try this like the answer down here.. 
$user->posts()->whereIn('status', ['Pending', 'Processing'])->paginate(5)

Answer (score 4):

Paginate method works with Eloquent models. Retrieve the model, apply whereIn first and then paginate it. Try this:

```
public function index() {
    $user = auth()->user();
    $validPosts = $user->posts()->whereIn('status', ['Pending', 'Processing'])->paginate(5);

    return view('home', $validPosts); 
}
```

Now in your "home" view file you can use $validPosts

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id; // gets the current user id
    $user = User::find($user_id); // find the specific user id


    // paginate function should be last
    $validPosts = $user->posts()->whereIn('status', ['Pending', 'Processing'])->paginate(5);


    // if you want to pass more variable, do it like this
    return view('home', ['validPosts' => $validPosts]);
}
```

or you can do it like this

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id; // gets the current user id 


    // paginate function should be last
    $validPosts = Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->whereIn('status', ['Pending', 'Processing'])->paginate(5);


    // if you want to pass more variable, do it like this
    return view('home', ['validPosts' => $validPosts]);
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I am glad that I help you :)